# Symfony Form - Automatically add a fixed number of children to collection

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to build a form with a collection which contains a fixed number of children when I create the parent entity. It should not allow adding more children.
On edit, it should get the children automatically and not allow adding more children.

With the code below, the form is rendered but no collection children are shown.

Parent form :

```
$builder->add('items', CollectionType::class, ['entry_type' => ItemFormType::class]);
```

ItemFormType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('sujet', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('corrige', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('vrai', CheckboxType::class)
    ;

        $builder
            ->add('annule', CheckboxType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Item::class
    ]);
}
```

Twig :

```
{% for item in form.items %}
    {% set nomItem = 'Item'~loop.index %}
    {{ nomItem }}
   {{ form_row(item.vrai) }}
   {{ form_row(item.annule) }}
   {{ form_row(item.sujet) }}
   {{ form_row(item.corrige) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Item (child) Entity :

```
class Item
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="QC", inversedBy="items", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="qc_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $qc;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sujet", type="text")
 */
private $sujet;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="corrige", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $corrige;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="vrai", type="boolean")
 **/
private $vrai;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="annule", type="boolean")
 **/
private $annule;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="ordre", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $ordre;
}
```

QC (parent) Entity :

```
class QC {
    ....
        /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="qc", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "asc"})
 */
protected $items;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, above the rule

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

add your children to the parent entity.

```
$parent = new Parent();
for($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
    $child = new Child(); // instantiate a new child entity
    $parent->addChild($child); // add this instance to the parent entity
}
/* now build your form and handle the request vars if form has been posted */
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ParentType', $parent);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

This way, you could 'initialize' new entities in many ways before you show the form...

Comment: I tried this and it's the same in the view. I don't have any children in the collection.

Comment: Be sure that the children are persisted tot the database when you submit the form. To help you more with that you could update your question with the (relevant) code of your entities

Comment: I added the code from my entities. I don't understand why you talk about when the form is submitted. What I want is first to show 5 children in the collection when I create a new QC entity.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but this answer might still be relevant for others.
You can also define the initial relations in the `construct` of the parent class like this:

```
class QC {
    ....

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="qc", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"order" = "asc"})
     */
    protected $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection([
            new Item(),
            new Item(),
            new Item(),
            new Item(),
            new Item(),
            new Item()
        ]);
    }
}
```

You'd still have to validate the amount of relations in your controller on submit.